# How to Pass multiple objects with "context" in WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I'm using this following code pass data to my third controller:

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ThirdView" context:MyArray];
```

The thing is, I would like to pass more than a simple array. I would like to pass a separate string, and another array if possible, and I don't want to add the string or the other array to "MyArray".

Is there a different way of going about this, or do I just restructure this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create custom object with the data you want to pass or you can bundle the data in the dictionary or array. In swift you can use tuple as well.

This is an example with dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myData = @{
    @"MainArray" : MyArray,
    @"MyString" : @"string",
    @"AnotherArray" : anotherArray
};
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ThirdView" context: myData];
```

Example with Array:

```
NSArray *myData = @[MyArray, @"string", anotherArray];
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ThirdView" context: myData];
```

Comment: This is in objective C, and I can kinda see how you could mush all the data into a dictionary object, but what do you mean by creating a custom object to put all the data in?

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* use a dictionary or an array as [Greg has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31378401/2613662), you get no type-safety and you have to ensure that the key names / indexes are the same in both places.

A better approach would be to subclass `NSObject` and provide a wrapper for the data you are wanting to transfer to that view controller.

Interface:

```
@interface ThirdViewState : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *list;

@end
```

Simple empty implementation:

```
@implementation ThirdViewState

@end
```

Then you can construct an instance of this object, populate it with data and pass it to the view controller:

```
ThirdViewState *state = [[ThirdViewState alloc] init];
state.title = @"My 3rd view";
state.list = myArray;
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ThirdView" context:state];
```

Then in the third view controller's awakeWithContext: method you can pull out the data:

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(ThirdViewState *)state {
   [super awakeWithContext:state];
   // do whatever with state
}
```

Comment: Perhaps slightly pedantic but I think it would be nicer with a custom init defined on ThirdViewState such as `-(void)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title list:(NSArray *)list;`